# Nodejs Sync functions?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to set it to true and only then redirect to another page. However I get redirected first and then it's set to true..

Code:

```
exports.logIn= function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.loggedIn = true;

  res.redirect("/home");
};
```

Comment: why are you mutating session variable ? this work should be done in passport

Comment: It should not. How do you verify it `redirect` first and set to `true` later?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using res.locals

```
exports.logIn= function(req, res, next) {
//AUTHENTICATE
  res.locals.loggedIn = true;
  res.redirect("/home");
};
```

Then on '/home' route you can check the user is logged in or not by reading res.locals.loggedIn

```
if(res.locals.loggedIn){
 // DO SOMETHING
} else {
 //REDIRECT TO LOGIN
}
```